# How do I make JTextArea scrollable?

Tags: java, swing, jscrollpane, jtextarea

I've been trying to add `JScrollBar` into a `JTextArea`, but when I test it the scrollbar does not show up. Also, I want to maximize the text area but it does not become larger even when I change the size value. Here is my code:

```
class EFrame extends JFrame implements ActionListener {
    JLabel jl1, jl2, jl3, jl5;
    JTextArea jta;
    JPanel jpBase, jpTop, jpm, jpmm, jpmb, jpBottom, jpBBT;
    JTextField jtf1, jtf2, jtf3, jtf4, jtf5;
    JScrollBar jBar;
    JScrollPane jsp;

    EFrame() {
        setTitle("GUI");
        setSize(1000, 1000);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(100, 100));
        this.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(1920, 1080));

        jsp = new JScrollPane(jta, JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED, JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);

        jpBase = new JPanel();
        jpTop = new JPanel();
        jpm = new JPanel();
        jpmm = new JPanel();
        jpmb = new JPanel();
        jpBottom = new JPanel();
        jpBBT = new JPanel();

        jtf1 = new JTextField(10);
        jtf2 = new JTextField(10);
        jtf3 = new JTextField(10);
        jtf5 = new JTextField(10);

        add(jpBase);
        jpBase.setLayout(new GridLayout(8, 1));
        jpBase.setSize(1000, 1000);
        jpBase.add(jpTop);
        jpBase.add(jpm);
        jpBase.add(jpmm);
        jpBase.add(jpmb);
        jpBase.add(jpBottom);
        jpBase.add(jpBBT);

        jpTop.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 0));

        jpm.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 0));
        jpmm.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 0));
        jpBottom.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 0));
        jpBBT.setSize(1000, 1000);
        jpBBT.add(jta);
        jta.setSize(1000, 1000);
        jta.add(jsp);
        this.setVisible(true);
    }
    // ...
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Well, right off the bat you are not constructing your JTextArea anywhere

Comment: JTextArea is at the bottom

Comment: *JTextArea is at the bottom* - setting the size of the text area does not create an instance of the text area. Your code should not execute. You should be getting a NullPointerException.

Answer (score 1):

```
JTextArea jta;
```

That code does not create an instance of the text area. It only defines a reference that is null.

Your code should be something like:

```
JTextArea jta = new JTextArea(10, 40);
```

The above code will create a text area with 10 row and 40 columns.

Then you create the scroll pane using the text area (which is correct):

```
jsp = new JScrollPane(jta, JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED, JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);
```

Note: all you need is:

```
jsp = new JScrollPane(jta);
```

The default behaviour is to only display the scrollbars when needed.

Then you do:

```
 jpBBT.add(jta);
```

A component can only have a single parent. So the second statement is removing the text area from the scroll pane.

The code should be:

```
//jpBBT.add(jta);
jpBBT.add(jsp);
```

Now you need to get rid of:

```
    //jta.setSize(1000, 1000);
    //jta.add(jsp)
```

1. setting the size does nothing. Using the rows/columns is the proper way to specify a size.
2. it makes no sense to add the scroll pane to the text area. You already added the text area to the scroll pane. You can't do both.

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to use Text Areas](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/textarea.html) for more information and working code. Download the working code and use it as a starting point for you class so your code is better structured.

Also, use descriptive variable names to make your code easier to read and understand and maintain.